# AngularJS with directive dynamic templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to use dynamic templates in the directive. I use replaceWith() method for this:

```
var template;
switch (scope.type) {

  case 'type1':
      template = angular.element('<div>Type1</div>');
      break;

  case 'type2':
      template = angular.element('<div>Type2</div>');
      break;
}

element.replaceWith(template);
```

It is works fine before adding new element in the scope. When $scope is updated I see both elements in my container:

```
<some-content ng-repeat="content in contents" type="content.type" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></some-content>
<div class="test">Type1</div>
<some-content ng-repeat="content in contents" type="content.type" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></some-content>
<div class="test">Type2</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6g35519z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually not a good practice in Angular to dynamically lay out the view; you should really be creating a single layout that dynamically displays its parts. This can be done either with the [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive for lone components with binary states, or [`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) for switch cases (as yours is).

```
<div ng-switch="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="type1">Type1</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type2">Type2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. The problem is that I need these templates in other place. I do not want duplicate them.

Comment: You may want to make them individual directives, then, and include them as such in the `ng-switch` block. They'll be portable and reusable.

Comment: It is a good idea. I use this trick with templates in jQuery UI Draggable helper method. I do not know how use directives in this case.

Comment: In jQuery, what you're doing absolutely makes sense. A fundamental gap between jQuery and Angular, though, and the reason why you should avoid mixing them, is because jQuery is a way to control your DOM, while Angular is a way to say what you want the DOM to ultimately look like, and then give the data needed to do it.

As far as not knowing how to use directives, what _do_ you know about them? What might you have trouble with?

Comment: OK, I think it is another question. I will try understand directives fully and reorganize my application with angular ideology. Thank you for your help.